# Renaming values in a column from lists within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like this,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2':list('AASOSP')})
df
```

and I have two lists,

```
lis1=['A']
Lis2=['S','O']
```

I need to replace the value in col2 based on the lis1 and lis2.
So I used `np.where` to do so.
like this,

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col2.isin(lis1),'PC',df.col2.isin(lis2),'Ln','others')
```

But its throwing me follwoing error,

> TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)
>   Any suggestion is very appreciated.!!

At the end I am aiming to have the values replace in col2 of my data frame as,

```
    col1    col2
0   1   PC
1   2   PC
2   3   Ln
3   4   Ln
4   5   Ln
5   6   others
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
lis1=['A']
lis2=['S','O']

df['col2'] = np.where(df.col2.isin(lis1),'PC',
             np.where(df.col2.isin(lis2),'Ln','others'))

print (df)
   col1    col2
0     1      PC
1     2      PC
2     3      Ln
3     4      Ln
4     5      Ln
5     6  others
```

**Timings**:

```
#[60000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [257]: %timeitnp.where(df.col2.isin(lis1),'PC',np.where(df.col2.isin(lis2),'Ln','others'))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.15 ms per loop

In [258]: %timeit in1d_based(df, lis1, lis2)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.98 ms per loop
```

Comment: Added timings into my post after using a function version with the same setup as yours and timings are different. I am guessing `%%timeit ` timings does something different than `%timeit `.

Comment: Interesting, I test it in windows and in python 3.

Comment: Try it with my function version `in1d_based`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach -

```
a = df.col2.values
df.col2 = np.take(['others','PC','Ln'], np.in1d(a,lis1) + 2*np.in1d(a,lis2))
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
# Input dataframe
In [206]: df
Out[206]: 
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    A
2     3    S
3     4    O
4     5    S
5     6    P

# Extract out col2 values
In [207]: a = df.col2.values

# Form an indexing array based on where we have matches in lis1 or lis2 or neither
In [208]: idx = np.in1d(a,lis1) + 2*np.in1d(a,lis2)

In [209]: idx
Out[209]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0])

# Index into a list of new strings with those indices
In [210]: newvals = np.take(['others','PC','Ln'], idx)

In [211]: newvals
Out[211]: 
array(['PC', 'PC', 'Ln', 'Ln', 'Ln', 'others'], 
      dtype='|S6')

# Finally assign those into col2
In [212]: df.col2 = newvals

In [213]: df
Out[213]: 
   col1    col2
0     1      PC
1     2      PC
2     3      Ln
3     4      Ln
4     5      Ln
5     6  others
```

Runtime test -

```
In [251]: df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'col2':list('AASOSP')})

In [252]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [253]: lis1
Out[253]: ['A']

In [254]: lis2
Out[254]: ['S', 'O']

In [255]: def in1d_based(df, lis1, lis2):
     ...:     a = df.col2.values
     ...:     return np.take(['others','PC','Ln'], np.in1d(a,lis1) + 2*np.in1d(a,lis2))
     ...: 

# @jezrael's soln
In [256]: %timeit np.where(df.col2.isin(lis1),'PC', np.where(df.col2.isin(lis2),'Ln','others'))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.78 ms per loop

In [257]: %timeit in1d_based(df, lis1, lis2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: @user1017373 Its NumPy equivalent of `isin`.

Comment: and 2*np.in1d ?

Comment: @user1017373 That helps us assign `2` for matches against `lis2` elements.

Comment: wow! this is nice __generic__ solution which allows us to avoid nested `np.where()` calls - added to my recipes collections!

Comment: @MaxU Yup! For more lists though, we need to use `3*ini1d()` and so on. Maybe we could make that part elegant too, I am thinking `searchsorted`, but that would need `sorting` and lots of messiness around that sorting itself.